# Prioritizing a list/table row

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, web-app, design-patterns, tables

I have a table structure where each row is an item,now my use case involves prioritizing it based on certain parameters such that item with highest priority would come at the top.
I will have a large number of such items (around 10-20k) hence looking out for UX suggestions for this screen the ease the process.
Some of the things that I thought were:

- drag and drop each item
- have up and down arrows against each item

Let me know your suggestions.

Comment: If priority is based on certain parameter then why drag and drop or arrows?

Comment: those parameters are really based on discussions after every 3 months,based on the decision someone would manually set the prioritization accordingly.My use case is quite similar to this : http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/61024/prioritizing-items-from-a-list-of-values , except that I have a lot more items in my bucket to be prioritized.

Answer (score 2):

You could introduce some way to set a specific priority (an icon, double clicking the existing priority column, etc). If I need to move from 345 to 13, I double click the 345 and type 13, hit enter and that row zips up to position 13 (former 13->14, 14->15, etc).

I would likely combine multiple solutions. Click and Type is good for setting a specific priority or making big leaps (10,000 -> 100). Then something like Drag and Drop is convenient for moving something a relatively small distance (100 -> 96), but less convenient for large jumps.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop is more convenient and can move multiple rows

Many arrange 10-20k is a lot of manual

Comment: wouldn't that be cumbersome if I need to move an entry at say 345th position to maybe 13th position. Just thinking out loud here...

Comment: And you think 300 plus button clicks would be more convenient?

Comment: No I am not really a fan of that approach either,hence looking out for better suggestions :)